# Calling a Webservice from VBA using SOAP

Tags: web-services, vba, excel

I'm trying to call a web service in an Excel Macro:

```
Set objHTTP = New MSXML.XMLHTTPRequest
objHTTP.Open "post", "https://www.server.com/EIDEServer/EIDEService.asmx"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "PutSchedule"
objHTTP.send strXML
```

And I get back the following response:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
        <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
        <faultstring>Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: PutSchedule.</faultstring>
        <detail />
      </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
```

Anybody out there done something like this before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You SOAP action should also include namespace of the method
e.g.

```
"http://tempri.org/PutSchedule"
```

Find out what the namespace of your Service and add it in front of the method name PutSchedule.

Comment: could you please be a little more specific? I know this message is more than 3 years old, but that is the point of having such forums, right?

Answer (score 2):

looks more like you're using xml-rpc instead of soap.
interact with the webservice using the soap type library at : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa192537(office.11).aspx, or the one that corresponds with your ms office version